# Changing items in jComboBox by clicking a jRadiobutton

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox, jradiobutton

Is it possible that the items in `jComboBox` change by clicking a `jRadioButton`? For instance: the first `jRadioButton` is selected and there are five options in `jComboBox`. When you click another `jRadiobutton`from the same button group, the options from `jComboBox` are replaced with the new ones. Do I need to use `ActionListener`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. But I recommend using ItemListener instead of ActionListener.
In the itemStateChanged methode, check if radio button is selected.

```
radioButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {        
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            //change your combobox
        }
        else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            //change to another
        }
    }
});
```